# Flexible class design that adheres to open-close principle

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm playing with some application and doing a little refactoring in order to make it more flexible. As I expected, a lot of problems arose. 
For example i'm trying to find optimal way to delete items from collections in Spaceship class

```
class Spaceship{
 List<Weapon> Weapons {get;set;}
 List<Shield> Shields {get;set;}

 public void RemoveEquipment(Equipment item){
 switch(item.EquipmentType )
 {
   case EquipmentType.Weapon:
     weapons.Remove(item);
     break;
   case EquipmentType.Shield:
     shields.Remove(item);
     break;
 }    
 }

 public void AddEquipment(Equipment item){
 //works the same way as RemoveEquipment
 }

}

class Equipment{    
 //EquipmentType is enum
 EquipmentType Type {get;set;};
}

class Weapon: Equipment{    
}

class Shield:Equipment{
}

class AutoCannon:Weapon{
}

class LaserGun:Weapon {

}
```

Is there a better way? What if I want to delete group of items of the same subtype (e.g. every LaserGun in weapons collection - without using reflection) 
And if I want to add a new type of Equipment, the methods responsible for adding/deleting have to be modified (switch/case).

Comment: Do you really need to have the `Weapons` and `Shields` setters as well? If you can make these readonly properties, you can easily use generics for a better and shorter code. Also, can a ship have multiple weapons or shields? because if it can, then these properties should be an `IEnumerable<Weapon>` and `IEnumerable<Shield>` instead of a single `Weapon` or `Shield`.

Comment: My mistake, those properties are collections

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, you do not want to expose properties of type `List`, especially if they are not readonly. I would suggest changing the `Weapons` and `Shields` properties to either `IEnunerable` or at the very least `IReadOnlyList` - and make them readonly.

Having said that, your `Spaceship` class can look like this:

```
// internal is the default access modifier for types, but it's more descriptive to specify it. 
internal class Spaceship
{

    private List<Equipment> _equipment = new List<Equipment>();

    public IEnumerable<Weapon> Weapons {get {return _equipment.OfType<Weapon>();}}
    public IEnumerable<Shield> Shields {get {return _equipment.OfType<Shield>();}}

    public void RemoveEquipment(Equipment item)
    {
        _equipment.Remove(item);
    }

    public void AddEquipment(Equipment item)
    {
        _equipment.Add(item);
    }

}
```

And then, in order to remove all equipments of a specific type, you can do something like this:

```
public void RemoveEquipment<T>() where T : Equipment
{
    _equipment.RemoveAll(e => e is T);
}
```

You can also add a bunch of equipment at the same time:

```
public void AddEquipment(IEnumerable<Equipment> items)
{
    _equipment.AddRange(items);
}
```

Note that there are no more cumbersome switch statements and almost nothing involving the specific type of the equipment - except when you explicitly need shields and weapons.

The main benefit, of course, is that when adding a new type of equipment, you don't need to change your `Spaceship` class to support it (Unless, of course, you want to have a property specialized for that specific type of equipment like `Weapons` or `Shields`).